# bytefield doesn't work with subfigures

Tags: subfloats, bytefield

I'm trying to use `bytefield` and `subfig` (and also tested with `subfigure` with the same results) but I got the error:

> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed
>
> to \cr.  \endtemplate

at the end of the `subfloat` environment.

The code below reproduces the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% this works
\begin{figure}
\begin{bytefield}{16}
\wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field} \\
\bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits} \\
\wordbox{2}{A 32-bit field. Note that text wraps within the box.}
\end{bytefield}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

% this doesn't
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{bytefield}{16}
\wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field} \\
\bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits} \\
\wordbox{2}{A 32-bit field. Note that text wraps within the box.}
\end{bytefield}
}% the error is trown here
\subfloat[]{
\begin{bytefield}{16}
\wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field} \\
\bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits} \\
\wordbox{2}{A 32-bit field. Note that text wraps within the box.}
\end{bytefield}
}% and here
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: error pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bytefield` environment doesn't like to be in the argument to a command, in this case `\subfloat`.

You can remedy by using a save bin and the environment `lrbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newsavebox{\bytefieldbox}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{lrbox}{\bytefieldbox}
\begin{bytefield}{16}
\wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field} \\
\bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits} \\
\wordbox{2}{A 32-bit field. Note that text wraps within the box.}
\end{bytefield}
\end{lrbox}
\subfloat[]{\usebox{\bytefieldbox}}
%%%
\begin{lrbox}{\bytefieldbox}
\begin{bytefield}{16}
\wordbox{1}{A 16-bit field} \\
\bitbox{8}{8 bits} & \bitbox{8}{8 more bits} \\
\wordbox{2}{A 32-bit field. Note that text wraps within the box.}
\end{bytefield}
\end{lrbox}
\subfloat[]{\usebox{\bytefieldbox}}

\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `lrbox` worked, while using `\sbox` did not? Is somehow different in comparison to `\sbox`?

Comment: @adn `\sbox` suffers from the same problem, because the text is absorbed as an argument, and `bytefield` doesn't like it.

Comment: So, internally the environments work somehow differently? What is inside is not treated like an argument?

Comment: @adn In general environments are not considered as arguments to a command (notice that this is instead the case for the alignments in `amsmath`). The purpose of `lrbox` is exactly not absorbing the text as an argument, but packaging it in a box nonetheless. It uses some really slick tricks.