# How to use footnotes in a bytefield?

Tags: footnotes, bytefield

At the moment I am trying to use `\footnote` inside the `rightwordgroup` and `leftwordgroup` environments of a `bytefield`, as well as inside the labels given to the fields themselves.

The numbering at the text indicates that `\footnote` had some effect, but the footnote - if there is any added at all - does not appear in the footer.

Is the solution similar to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152925/3925)?

Comment: Maybe `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion from [John](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25356/john-wickerson) really helped. Separating the `\footnotemark` from `footnotetext` and combining it the way seen in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43694/3925) worked for me:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}{32}
    \bitheader{0,15,31} \\
    \begin{rightwordgroup}{\textbf{header\footnote{Some explanation}}}
        \bitbox{16}{Magic bytes} &
        \bitbox{16}{Size\footnote{size of header}}
    \end{rightwordgroup} \\
\end{bytefield}

\newpage
\setcounter{footnote}{0} % reset for demonstration purposes

\begin{bytefield}{32}
    \bitheader{0,15,31} \\
    \begin{rightwordgroup}{\textbf{header\footnotemark{}}}
        \bitbox{16}{Magic bytes} &
        \bitbox{16}{Size\footnotemark{}}
    \end{rightwordgroup} \\
\end{bytefield}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-2} % we used \footnotemark how many times above?
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Some explanation}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{size of header}
\end{document}
```

The first `bytefield` environment (page 1) shows the issue I had, the second (page 2) shows the workaround.